# In flutter asset.network() isn't working when I add the URL of the image the phone shows nothing

Tags: flutter

In flutter asset.network() isn't working when I add the URL of the image the phone shows nothing. what do I want to do now?

```
AppBar(
        title: Text('my first app'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here I'm getting images as a circular, just try it

```
String imageLink = "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9";
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 160.0,
                    width: 160.0, 
                    child: new CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageLink),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```